# much out of repair

Tags: meaning

> "Experience has shown you the difference of the results between
> mechanism which is neat, clean, well-arranged and always in a high
> state of repair, and that which is allowed to be dirty, in disorder,
> and which therefore **becomes much out of repair**. ... If, then, due care
> as to the state of your inanimate machines can produce such beneficial
> results, what may not be expected if you devote equal attention to
> your vital machines, which are far more wonderfully constructed?"

[A New View of Society, Robert Owen]

Does "becomes much out of repair" mean "frequently breaks down"?

Comment: Robert Owen wrote that in 1813. 1. The what/which distinction was much more fluid then. 2. Yes.

Comment: On this site, we're only allowed to ask one question at a time. Although your questions both relate to phrases in the same paragraph, they are not related in terms of their content. If both are important to you, please ask a second question, including the same paragraph, and ask about the second phrase there. Rather than close this question for breaking the "Needs more focus" rule, I've removed the question not mentioned in the title. Feel free to open a second question to ask the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Owen (1771 – 1858) published *A New View of Society* in 1813. The use of  interrogative pronouns as relative pronouns (e.g. what, who, which, where, when, why, and how) first appeared in Old and Middle English around 1000 - 1200 AD. All of these are still in common use in Standard English except for what, which seems to have become non-standard sometime between 1750 and 1850 or so. So Owen was using 'what' in an archaic but still acceptable way.

'Out of repair' (of a machine, or something else like a building) does, as you ask, mean 'broken' or 'not working properly' (because of neglect or lack of maintenance). The opposite is 'in repair', or very often, 'in good repair'. You might still say in modern English that a house or bridge or car is in good repair if it has been maintained properly.

Answer (score 3):

The English is old and was, I suspect, not standard formal English of the time.

The question is rhetorical and means

> An indeterminate but great improvement can be expected if we pay as much attention to the proper care of workers as we do to the proper care of the workers’ tools.